# How to get data from Humminbird ChartSelect .bin file

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding, binary, hex

I purchased some lake bathymetry data from humminbird ChartSelect. I can see those data using their applications such as FishSmart or also using the Humminbird sonar module. But I would like to read those data as a CSV file with X, Y, Depth values. Is there any way to do so? I want to use this data to some python program.

Here I'm attaching the screenshot of the data in their application. [image]

Also, the file looks like this[image]
Also, one of the bin file [image]

Comment: Did you look at PyHum?